# Improve PHP FTP execution speed?

Tags: php, file, ftp, ftp-client

I am trying to upload images and files with FTP using PHP code. But while uploading, it's taking too much time for uploading large files. I compared FileZilla direct uploading speed(drag and drop in FileZilla) and my PHP's FTP code. I found there is one big difference. The FileZilla is super fast as compared with normal PHP FTP's code. Can I improve the speed of FTP transfer using PHP code?

Comment: Filezilla likely uses multiple threads, whereas I'm suspecting your code might not, although we aren't mind readers...

Comment: Please read this :  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry guys. I am new in stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using file transfer acceleration software? For example FileCatalyst TransferAgent can be embedded using JavaScript into web page and can provide fast file transfer on almost any web page (including PHP). With FileCatalyst TransferAgent, you will be able to transfer files with acceleration, transfer complex folder structures and capture all the events back to JavaScript (Transfer complete, transfer error etc...)

Here is a link to the product: https://filecatalyst.com/solutions/filecatalyst-direct/

Yes I work for FileCatalyst.